# Making a scroll function more efficient in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, though I'm not sure it is efficient as it could be.

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollT = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollT >= 180) {
        $("#primary-nav-wrapper").addClass("scroll");
        $("#primary-nav-wrapper li.front").addClass("active");


        $("#primary-nav-wrapper .search-wrapper").removeClass("active");
        $("#primary-nav-wrapper .search-field").blur();
    }
    else {
        $("#primary-nav-wrapper").removeClass("scroll");
        $("#primary-nav-wrapper .search-wrapper, #primary-nav-wrapper li.front").removeClass("active");

        $("#primary-nav-wrapper .search-field").blur();
    }
    if (scrollT >= 400) {$("a#to-top-link").addClass("active");}
    else {$("a#to-top-link").removeClass("active");}
});
```

Basically, what I do here is checking two if-clauses every time I scroll, but is it more resource-friendly to only check every few milliseconds? If so, how is this done? Or is it a better idea to re-write the if-else structure, e.g. *if.. else if... else if... else*?

Comment: What does setting the `active` class accomplish? Could you make a live Stack Snippet example including some HTML and CSS?

Comment: @200_success The classes trigger CSS3 animations, which I prefer over JS enabled ones. I don't think a live example would be helpful because the code works perfectly, but I was simply wondering if it could be optimised a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you mean general performance, but one thing I've heard helps a lot is to put all of your different selectors in variables outside of the function as it is apparently pretty expensive to make the selector calls again and again. I mean something like this (and I do mean "something like this" because I haven't tested even the basics, but the general idea is described here: http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#cache-jquery-objects)

```
var scroll = {
     primary  : $("#primary-nav-wrapper"),
     front    : $("#primary-nav-wrapper li.front"),
     search_w : $("#primary-nav-wrapper .search-wrapper"),
     search_f : $("#primary-nav-wrapper .search-field"),
     to_top   : $("a#to-top-link")
}
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollT = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollT >= 180) {
        scroll.primary.addClass("scroll");
        scroll.front.addClass("active");


        scroll.search_w.removeClass("active");
        scroll.search_f.blur();
    }
    else {
        scroll.primary.removeClass("scroll");
        scroll.front.removeClass("active");

        scroll.search_f.blur();
    }
    if (scrollT >= 400) {scroll.to_top.addClass("active");}
    else {scroll.to_top.removeClass("active");}
});
```

Comment: Would it possibly be an even further optimisation when saying for instance `front: primary.find("li.front")`?

Comment: Sure. But a very minor one as you're only doing it once. Mostly in your case, you want to keep the dom traversal out of the "scroll" part because that is firing a lot (on every user scroll). For the set up, which runs only once per page load, I'd go with whatever is clearer to you.